# Apache document root doesn't change

Tags: linux, permissions, centos, apache-http-server

So I installed apache on a virtual server using VMware on CentOS 7 minimal using:

```
yum install -y httpd
```

When I tried to change the DocumentRoot at `vim /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`
 , nothing happens and it keeps reading the default apache page. so I searched for the file, it's neither at /var/www nor /var/www/html , so I executed:

```
locate index.html | grep -r Testing
```

Till I found it at this path `/usr/share/httpd/noindex` where I changed the html a couple of times till I got sure this is where it is listening. Ports are open, permissions are all set to the user and group "apache".

I am wondering what could possibly be wrong and causing such a behavior.

Comment: Did you restart httpd after editing the conf file?

Comment: Of course, I even restarted the whole server as well.

Comment: What does `apache2ctl -S` show as far as config files?  Is it possible that you have multiple configs, with different `DocumentRoot` directives?

Answer (score 0):

Try `grep -r DocumentRoot /etc/httpd`, that'll show you all references of `DocumentRoot` in your configuration files. There probably are other declarations of `DocumentRoot`, possibly within `VirtualHost` tags, that define other paths.